# why Laravel considers category as locale

Tags: laravel, routes, localization

I am stuck with laravel localization. I want locale optional in my routes. But issue is that if locale is not send i want en by default. If locale is not explicitly in URL. Laravel considers first parameter like category as Locale.

```php
Route::group(["prefix"=>'{locale?}','middleware'=>'getLang'],function() {   
    Route::get('/',[WebsiteController::class,'get_homepage'])->name('homepage');
    Route::get('{category}',[WebsiteController::class,'category_all_news'])->name('category_all_news')->middleware('getLang');
    Route::get('{category}/{slug}',[WebsiteController::class,'get_a_news_blog'])->name('get_a_news_blog')->middleware('getLang');  
});
```

How can i solve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should always pass optional param in the last part of the url or as a query string. Otherwise, you can make a middleware, if there is no lang mentioned, add the lang and redirect to new url.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to define optional parameters in your routes, by simply adding a question mark before them

In your case, you can add a parameter for the locale before your category

```
Route::get('/',[WebsiteController::class,'get_homepage'])->name('homepage');
Route::get('{locale?}/{category}',[WebsiteController::class,'category_all_news'])->name('category_all_news')->middleware('getLang');
Route::get('{locale?}/{category}/{slug}',[WebsiteController::class,'get_a_news_blog'])->name('get_a_news_blog')->middleware('getLang');
```

When passing the locale variable in your method you can just define a default value for the parameter

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters